# Problema al restar fechas de distinto formato

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo dos fechas, una con este formato `12/6/23 22:47` que llamaremos `FECHA1`, y la otra fecha es la fecha actual dada por JavaScript:

```
fechaActual = new Date();
```

Esta última fecha se muestra así:

```
Mon Jun 12 2023 23:02:26 GMT+0200 (hora de verano de Europa central)
```

Esta fecha es la que muestra JavaScript por defecto cuando hago un `new Date();`.

Necesito poder restar estas fechas para ver los minutos que han pasado, no tengo mucha idea de como hacerlo. La primera fecha he intentado con la `FECHA1` hacer:

```
FECHA1 = new Date(FECHA1);
```

Pero al hacer un `alert` me da una fecha de diciembre.

Espero haberme explicado bien, un saludo.

Comment: Obtienes el mes de diciembre porque tu fecha no está en el formato ISO. Debería estar de la siguiente forma: `06/12/2023 22:47`.

Comment: Gracias Cris, lo que necesito es pasar esa fecha en fecha formato javascript para poder restarlas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Qué tal, Lorenzo?

Como utilizas un formato diferente de fecha, tendrías que cambiarlo a partir de los datos que integran la cadena con la fecha.

Para ello puedes utilizar el método `split()` con el cual se puede separar una cadena a partir de un símbolo dado, como en este caso serían el `/` y el `:`, además del espacio en blanco entre la fecha y la hora.

```javascript
//La cadena con la fecha y hora
const myDatetime = "12/6/23 22:47";

//La fecha y hora del sistema
const realDatetime = new Date();

//Se separa la cadena a partir del espacio entre la fecha y la hora
const splitString = myDatetime.split(" "); //Array("12/6/23", "22:47")

//Se separan los elementos de la fecha
const splitDate = splitString[0].split("/"); //Array("12", "6", "23")

//Se separan los elementos de la hora
const splitTime = splitString[1].split(":"); //Array("22", "47")
```

Con los elementos separados, y para tener más orden y claridad, se puede asignar cada valor a variables cuyos nombres sean fáciles de identificar.

```javascript
const day = splitDate[0]; //El día
const month = splitDate[1]; //El mes
const year = splitDate[2]; //El año
const hours = splitTime[0]; //La hora
const minutes = splitTime[1]; //Los minutos
```

Enseguida, tendrás que restarle una unidad al valor del mes, esto debido a que el objeto `Date` de JavaScript trabaja con los meses de una manera similar a como lo hacen los arreglos y sus índices; es decir, empezando por el cero, lo cual quiere decir que, por ejemplo, el mes dado como 6, será interpretado como el séptimo. Asimismo, como el formato de la fecha es de cuatro dígitos, tendrás que completar la parte faltante. Esto puedes hacerlo concatenando el `20` con el valor de la variable del año.

```
//Se le resta una unidad al valor del mes
const month = splitDate[1] - 1; //El mes

//Se le da el formato de cuatro dígitos al año
const year = `20${splitDate[2]}`; //El año
```

Ya con todos los valores separados y formateados, puedes construir un objeto de fecha:

```
const finalDatetime = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes);
```

Finalmente, solo quedará realizar la resta de forma directa y dividir el resultado, dado en milésimas de segundo, entre el producto de 60 por 1000, esto debido a que se requiere transformar las milésimas de segundo a segundos y estos a minutos. Además de ello, puedes usar la función `parseInt()` para que el resultado mostrado no contenga la parte decimal:

```
const diff = parseInt((finalDatetime - realDatetime) / (60 * 1000));
```

Para evitar obtener un resultado negativo, como cuando el minuendo es menor al sustraendo, puedes multiplicar el resultado por -1 o bien utilizar estructuras condicionales para asignar el minuendo y sustraendo de tal forma que evites una diferencia negativa.

Un ejemplo en uso:

```js
const myDatetime = "12/6/23 22:47";
const realDatetime = new Date();
const splitString = myDatetime.split(" ");
const splitDate = splitString[0].split("/");
const splitTime = splitString[1].split(":");

const day = splitDate[0];
const month = splitDate[1] - 1;
const year = `20${splitDate[2]}`;
const hours = splitTime[0];
const minutes = splitTime[1];

const finalDatetime = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes);
const diff = parseInt((finalDatetime - realDatetime) / (60 * 1000));

console.log(diff);
```

Puedes añadir la secuencia de instrucciones a una función para que puedas reutilizar el código todas las veces que lo necesites.

Un saludo

Comment: Muchisimas gracias. No se imagina lo que me ha ayudado.

Comment: De nada, @LorenzoMartín. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer aritmética de fechas, primero debes convertir la cadena de texto en fecha. Para ello, puedes valerte de una expresión regular para convertir la cadena a la forma ISO `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MI`, que será reconocida independientemente de la configuración local.

Luego, la resta entre dos fechas, te dará el número de milisegundos transcurridos entre ellas, por lo que es nada más de hacer la matemática para tener el número de minutos, por ejemplo:

```js
var d1 = "12/06/23 22:47"
var d1p = /(\d{2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2})/;
var dt1 = new Date(d1.replace(d1p,'20$3-$2-$1'));

var hoy = new Date();
console.log(dt1);
console.log(hoy);

var diffMs = (hoy - dt1); // milisegundos
var diffMin = diffMs / 1000 / 60;

console.log('Minutos', diffMin, 'ms', diffMs);
```

Observa que al hacer la sustitución para re-ordenar la fecha, estoy añadiendo el prefijo `"20"` al año, por lo que mi solución funcionará solo por los siguientes 76 años (aproximadamente).

Answer (score 0):

Si vas a recibir si o si la primer fecha en formato DD-MM-YY quizás te convenga crear una función que reciba el string y devuelva una fecha valida, es decir que pase de `12/6/23 22:47` al formato `6/12/23 22:47 GMT+0200`, y para recién ahí poder calcular los minutos de diferencia.

Teniendo las 2 fechas en formato string:

```
let fecha1 = '12/6/23 22:47'
let fecha2 = 'Mon Jun 12 2023 23:02:26 GMT+0200'
```

Creo la funcion que reciba la fecha, cambie de orden el dia con el mes, y agregando la zona horaria al final (GMT+0200) y despues use ese string para devolver un objeto Date valido:

```
const construirFechaValida = (date) => {
  let fechayhora = date.split(' ')
  let fecha = fechayhora[0].split('/')
  return new Date(
    `${fecha[1]}/${fecha[0]}/${fecha[2]} ${fechayhora[1]} GMT+0200`
  );
}
```

Construimos los objetos Date:

```
fecha1 = construirFechaValida(fecha1)
fecha2 = new Date(fecha2)
```

Definimos una función que calcule la diferencia entre las dos fechas usando Date.getTime() que obtiene el tiempo en milisegundos desde el [tiempo de Unix](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) hasta la fecha representada en el objeto Date, debemos restar los getTime() de ambas fechas, obtener su valor absoluto (por si obtenemos un numero negativo, pasarlo a positivo) ese resultado lo pasamos a segundos, lo redondeamos con Math.round() y lo devolvemos:

```
const distanciaEnMinutos = (a, b) => {
  let abs = Math.abs(a.getTime() - b.getTime())
  return Math.round(abs / (60 * 1000))
}

console.log(distanciaEnMinutos(fecha1, fecha2))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problema:

Obtienes una fecha incorrecta porque la fecha no es del formato [**ISO 8601**](https://www.progress.com/blogs/understanding-iso-8601-date-and-time-format):

```js
let fecha1 = new Date('12/6/23 22:47');
console.log(fecha1);
```

La fecha debería estar de la siguiente forma:

```js
let fecha1 = new Date('06/12/2023 22:47');
console.log(fecha1);
```

---

### Conversión de fecha:

Entonces, para convertir la fecha `12/6/23 22:47` al formato correcto `06/12/2023 22:47`, podemos usar al `/` como separador con el método `split()` y concatenar los elementos del array en el orden correcto y llenamos con `0` con `padStart(2, '0')` al día y al mes (ya que, por ejemplo, tienes un `6`, y con `padStart(2, '0')` devuelve `06`):

```js
let fechaString = '12/6/23 22:47';
let fechaElementos = fechaString.split('/');

let fechaISO = `${fechaElementos[1].padStart(2, '0')}/${fechaElementos[0].padStart(2, '0')}/20${fechaElementos[2]}`;

console.log(fechaISO);
```

---

### Diferencia de minutos:

Respecto a obtener la diferencia de minutos, puedes restar ambas fechas, obteniendo la diferencia en milisegundos, y luego hacer una conversión de milisegundos a minutos con `Math.floor()`:

```js
let fecha1 = new Date('06/12/2023 22:47');
let fechaActual = new Date();

let milisegundos = fechaActual - fecha1; // obtenemos la diferencia en milisegundos.
let minutos = Math.floor(milisegundos / 60000); // obtenemos los milisegundos en minutos.

console.log(minutos);
```

### Código final:

```js
// Conversión
let fechaString = '12/6/23 22:47';
let fechaElementos = fechaString.split('/');
let fechaISO = `${fechaElementos[1].padStart(2, '0')}/${fechaElementos[0].padStart(2, '0')}/20${fechaElementos[2]}`;

// Diferencia de minutos
let fecha1 = new Date(fechaISO);
let fechaActual = new Date();
let milisegundos = fechaActual - fecha1; // obtenemos la diferencia en milisegundos.
let minutos = Math.floor(milisegundos / 60000); // obtenemos los milisegundos en minutos.

console.log(minutos);
```