# Como calcular la diferencia de minutos entre dos fechas usando Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero calcular la diferencia de minutos entre dos fechas que ya estan formateadas en el formato HH:MM

Por alguna razon de formateo al compararlas me devuelve NaN

```
const url = "https://api.bluelytics.com.ar/v2/latest";

fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {

    //  La const Update es la primer fecha, que saco del JSON Url
    // updateTime la formatea para que solo muestre las horas y minutos
    const update = new Date(data.last_update);
    const updateTime = `${update.getHours()}:${update.getMinutes()}`;

    // genero y formateo la hora y minuto actuales:
    let currentDate = new Date(); 
    let currentTime = `${currentDate.getHours()}:${currentDate.getMinutes()}`;
       
    // cuando trato de comparar la primer hora y minutos con la segundo recibo NaN
       function compare(){ 
        console.log(currentTime - updateTime);

       }compare();

  });
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema al restar fechas de distinto formato](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/596435/problema-al-restar-fechas-de-distinto-formato)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes solucionarlo usando el método `getTime()` de cada una de las instancias de `Date`.

```
const url = "https://api.bluelytics.com.ar/v2/latest";

fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {

    const update = new Date(data.last_update);
    const updateTime = `${update.getHours()}:${update.getMinutes()}`;

    let currentDate = new Date(); 
    let currentTime = `${currentDate.getHours()}:${currentDate.getMinutes()}`;
       
    // Esto devolverá la diferencia en milisegundos entre las dos fechas.
    console.log(currentDate.getTime() - update.getTime());

  });
```

Comment: Hola XX, bienvenido y gracias por tu colaboración, para dejar una respuesta "más redondita", podrías agregar la fórmula para convertir a minutos los milisegundos.